# Open youtube app from my android app. How to pass the id?

Tags: java, android, youtube

I am quite new to Android. I need to make an app that displays a bunch videos in an overview that gets retrieved from a API on the internet

Here's what the API looks like:

> [{"name":"9VJirQKuoxs","image":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9VJirQKuoxs/default.jpg"}]

That works as I want. The "name: " is the video ID and I need to open the Youtube app and open this particulair video. How do I open this? I am coming from PHP development and I cannot figure it out since I am still in a "web" state of mind. Can anyone put me on the right path? Or maybe even provide an example?

Thanks, if I need to provide code please ask.

EDIT:

I tested to open the youtube app and it works but I need to open the app on a specific item that has been clicked on.

How do I get the variable of the clicked item? In this case the variable is a string called video_id
Here's the part where the variables get made:

```
String url = params[0];
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response;
            response = client.execute(get);
            InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            String json = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                json += line;
            }

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
            ArrayList<JSONFields> alData = new ArrayList<JSONFields>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONFields data = new JSONFields();
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                data.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                data.setUrl(obj.getString("url"));
                data.setVideoid(obj.getString("name"));

                alData.add(data);
            }
            System.out.println("Data returned sucessfully");
            return alData;
```

And here is the onclick listener

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setClickable(true);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            System.out.println(arg3);
           }
        });
```

Please help me out!

EDIT2:

```
package com.bounty4u.jsonparsing.data;

public class JSONFields {

    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String video_id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void setVideoid(String video_id){
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }

    public String getVideoid(){
        return video_id;
    }
}
```

Also this is the error log:

> 05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at com.bounty4u.jsonparsing.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:49)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1202)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2975)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3657)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4765)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   05-22 16:44:42.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

EDIT:

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
            ArrayList<JSONFields> alData = new ArrayList<JSONFields>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONFields data = new JSONFields();
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                data.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                data.setUrl(obj.getString("url"));
                data.setVideoid(obj.getString("video_id"));
                System.out.println("Video ID: " + obj.getString("video_id"));

                alData.add(data);
            }
```

Comment: Now that you have made the last edit, what is the output of the program when you click on a list item. Does it print Video ID to your log correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VJirQKuoxs")));`

Android will let you choose the way you want to open the video (browser or youtube app).
This should works on a real device but not on emulator.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [YouTubeIntents](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents). This is "A selection of static methods that create intents which navigate to specific activities within the main YouTube application."

The intent you are interested in is the [YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntent(context,videoId)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#createPlayVideoIntent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
/**
 * Put this in your activity
 */
public void playVideo(String videoId) {
    if(YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(this)) {
        Intent i = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntent(this, videoId);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

As for getting the videoId from the clicked list item it depends a bit on how you create your list and pass the data to it. Do you pass the returned list (named 'alData' in your example) to the list adapter? You can probably do something like this in AdapterView.onItemClick():

```
JSONFields data = (JSONFields)listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
String videoId = data.getVideoId();
```

I make a bunch of assumptions here. First of all I assume that your list is represented by a bunch of JSONField objects (your JSON parse function seem to indicate this). Second, I assume there's a JSONField.getVideoId() to match the setter that you already have.

Update: Since you mention a nullpointer when a list item is clicked there's a few things that could cause it. Either the listview, the adapter or the item is null. I'd suggest that you set a breakpoint in Eclipse at the first line of the click listener and see what's wrong. Alternatively you could try to use the AdapterView directly to [get the list item](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    JSONField item = (JSONField)arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(item != null) {
        String videoId = item.getVideoId();     
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i get the ID from the JSON to this part? I've got it in the listview displayed as text but I dont know how to pass it onto the youtube app

Comment: I've edited my code with the JSONFields class. I've copied and pasted the code you presented here and the App is able to start but crashes as soon as I click a list item/.

Comment: Ah, it might be that you should get the list item using the AdapterView instead. I'll update my answer

Comment: I've modified my code and it runs but it doesn't get the right ID. I tested out by declaring the videoId string above the != null if and it turns out that the item is infact NULL. I've tested out if the getVideoid method even gets called by putting a println in there but it doesn't print anything into my console. Am I not calling the right class? Or isn't there a right object or something? It returns NULL.

Comment: It should work. Weird. I think you need to post some more code. What do you do with the parsed data? How do you pass it to your list?

Comment: listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  listview.setClickable(true);
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
       JSONFields item = (JSONFields)arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
       if(item != null) {
           String videoid = item.getVideoid();   
           System.out.println(videoid);  
       } 
       /*

       System.out.println(videoId);*/
   }
   });

Comment: Please edit your question, the code is unreadable in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+videoId)); 
intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a more full example using Damien R's suggestion above. If it works for you, then the error must be elsewhere in your list handling code.

```
package com.redchillipadi.youtube;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String videoID = "9VJirQKuoxs";
        //TODO: Sanitize input to prevent code injection
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+videoID)));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```