# Open youtube app with the video from a json feed

Tags: java, android, youtube

I've already asked a question here: [Open youtube app from my android app. How to pass the id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691057/open-youtube-app-from-my-android-app-how-to-pass-the-id)

And I am still stuck at this point.
How do I open the Youtube app on the right video from the VIDEO ID parsed from the JSON.

Comment: What was wrong with Damian R's suggestion in the post you referenced?

Comment: It didnt work. I've edited my code like he asked but haven't got a reply ever since

Comment: @Hawiak, I have posted an answer to your original post. Check it. This question is likely to be closed because of being duplicated.