# Showing youtube video in WebView

Tags: android, iframe, youtube

I have some rough HTML coming from a website what I'm displaying in a WebView. In the HTML there's an iframe with a youtube video, and from what I've read they don't work. So my idea was to replace the iframe tag with an img tag (http://www.img.youtube.com/videoid/0.jpg) and make that a link to open the youtube app.

What would be the best way of me doing this? I tried using a replaceAll but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
if (mBundle.getString("youtubeKey") != null) {

        String youtubeKey = mBundle.getString("youtubeKey");
        sourceCode = sourceCode.replaceAll("/<iframe.*?</iframe>/si", "<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+youtubeKey+"/0.jpg");

        Log.d("FUApp", "Replaced");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this hopefully it will help you in both directions

[How can we play YouTube embeded code in an Android application using webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817805/how-can-we-play-youtube-embeded-code-in-an-android-application-using-webview)

[Open youtube app from my android app. How to pass the id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691057/open-youtube-app-from-my-android-app-how-to-pass-the-id)